# Content is pushed down

Tags: html, css

I would like to let my page look like the following:

[image]

However, currently it looks like that:

[my website](http://kaffeenator.com)

I tried to change the `padding-right / left`, but nothing changes within the menu.

```
<article style="padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px;" class="post-6 page type-page status-publish entry" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork"><header class="entry-header">
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I  appreciate your replies!

Comment: use `float: left` and `float: right` in this case.

Comment: @jiff  Thx for your reply! I change: `<article style="float: left; float: right;" class="post-6 page type-page status-publish entry" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork"`, however, the product view is still down.

Comment: ok let me work on your site with `inspect element`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here you go:

**first step:**

move `entry-content` div to `facet-container` beside `facet_selection` then change your `css` from:

```
.entry-content {
    float: left;
    width: 790px;
}
```

**to:**

```
 .entry-content {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

because your parent div is `entry-content` and that product div is `entry-content` too. you should change class name for ex. to `entry-content2` now set some style for it:

```
.entry-content2 {
    float: right;
    width: 795px;
}
```

**then change `css` from:**

```
#facet_selection {
    width: 22%;
    padding: 1%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
```

**to:**

```
#facet_selection {
    width: 260px;
    padding: 1%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
```

---

*ok, now your turn, you can change `width` or `padding` or `margin` as you want. I see you used many extra `padding` or `margin`, you can remove some. I did it on inspect element and it works, can't move all your website to JSFiddle, so follow my instruction.*

**result:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Apply the following rules:

```
.entry-content {
  width: 100%;
}

aside {
  float: right;
  width: 75%;
}
```

Comment: Thx for your reply! It doesn`t work yet. Btw haven´t downvoted you!

Comment: no worries, looks like it's at least looking better now.